# LGBM fails to overfit

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, lightgbm

I have this data:

```
x = np.array([[ 6.2120e-01],[ 8.4310e-01],[ 1.2467e+00],[ 1.0147e+00],[ 3.0860e-01],
       [ 5.2160e-01],[ 6.9720e-01],[ 4.2600e-01],[ 6.5200e-01],[ 1.3448e+00],
       [-3.5860e-01],[ 1.0618e+00],[ 1.0513e+00],[ 7.5890e-01],[ 2.8270e-01],
       [ 5.2180e-01],[ 3.9240e-01],[ 1.6279e+00],[ 1.8290e-01],[-4.1820e-01],
       [ 4.7030e-01],[-4.7610e-01],[-9.7580e-01],[-8.6500e-01],[-5.4680e-01],
       [ 5.8500e-02],[-9.4460e-01],[-3.5250e-01],[ 7.0000e-04],[-1.1193e+00],
       [ 9.1700e-02],[ 1.0910e-01]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

There is a high correlation of -0.68 between the feature and the target. However, when I train an LGBM on this data, it fails to overfit and always returns the prior probability of each class:

```
lgbm = LGBMClassifier()
lgbm.fit(x,y)
lgbm.predict_proba(x)

array([[0.6875, 0.3125],
       [0.6875, 0.3125],
       [0.6875, 0.3125],
       [0.6875, 0.3125],
       [0.6875, 0.3125],
       [0.6875, 0.3125],
       [0.6875, 0.3125],...
```

Changing hyper-parameters like `learning_rate`, `n_estimators`, etc. doesn't help. What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Regardless of the results, why would you use LGBM at all for such data? A single decision tree or logistic regression would suffice.

Comment: @Tim You are right. It is part of a dataset that I am working on. If I understand the reason behind this, it would help me with the whole dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you did not actually create any trees, because by default you need in each branch at least 20 records (but you only have 32 records in total) so that no branching happens. It helps to look at what the resulting model looks like (in this case, using `lgbm.booster_.trees_to_dataframe()`), which immediately shows that no splits were done. If you ask for e.g. only one record per branch (`LGBMClassifier(min_child_samples=1)`), you do get actual trees and different predictions depending on the feature value.